# connecting 2 mics to computer and assign each one to a different software. possible?

Tags: audio, microphone

need help with something simple.

I want to connect 2 microphones to my computer and assign each microphone to a different software.
instead of two programs listening to the same microphone - which I don't think is possible.
is it possible to do this? if so then how?

thank you for helping out

Comment: How are you connecting the mics? 3.5mm or USB? Also what software are you trying to use? Most software has an option in the settings to select the specific input device.

Comment: mic1 is connected through 3.5mm jack.
mic2 is built in the computer.
program1 will be zoom
program2 will be skype

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments above, the following should be helpful;

You should verify that you can see both Mics in your system sound settings.

For Zoom, when you start or join a meeting you can click on the little carrot arrow beside the 'Mute' button and select which input device you would like to use.

For Skype, select your profile picture, then Settings, then Audio & Video and then configure the Microphone option for the other Microphone not being used in Zoom.

I hope this helps, but let me know if it doesn't work!

-L_A